# parse array in laravel blade

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-blade

my view page consist `{{$data->attachment}}` which render

`[{"filename":"hello.jpg", "location":"/home/my_folder"}]`.

Here i tried to display file name in `view` page using

```
@foreach($data->attachment as $attachment)
   $attachment->filename
@endforeach
```

which gives me

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

i trying

`{{$data->attachment->filename}}`

which gives me

> Trying to get property of non-object

what i'm doing wrong? how can i display filename? thanks.

Comment: try by `$attachment = $data->attachment->toArray()` and pass this `$attachment` variable to view and iterate `foreach` loop.

Comment: what do you get when you var_dump($data->attachment)?

Comment: as mentioned in the question `[{"filename":"hello.jpg", "location":"/home/my_folder"}]`

Comment: thats not a var_dump, what i am trying to say is does that echo out as a string or is it an object

Comment: oh.. it's string.. got from db

Comment: Still you are allowed to use this method in view. Actually `foreach` needs array or object to iterate but you have JSON data. So try as below may it help: <?php $attachment = $data->attachment()->toArray(); ?> in your view

Comment: @AlankarMore i thought it was object. silly. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments, the value of `$data->attachment` is actually a string. In order to iterate over it in a loop you will need to convert it back to an array.

So if you change your loop to:

```
@foreach(json_decode($data->attachment) as $attachment)
   {{ $attachment->filename }}
@endforeach
```

you should get what you want.

I would add that the correct place for this conversion should really be in your controller, not your view.

Your question was not entirely clear so this is all assuming you knew what you were doing when you used a foreach loop, meaning you actually have multiple entries in the `$data->attachment array`. If it is just the one attachment and you are really just trying to get the filename, then you don't need a loop, all you need is to say:

```
{{ json_decode($data->attachment)->filename }}
```

and again I would add that really that all belongs in your controller so that in your view you would end up with something like `{{ $filename }}`